# Is `queue.Queue` thread-safe, when accessed by several subprocesses using `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have been using `queue.Queue` extensively in situations, where I execute multiple threads e.g. by using `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I've read from blogs that `queue.Queue` should be thread-safe, but does that mean it's thread-safe under the assumption that the Python interpreter only executes one thread at a time (**GIL**), or is it also thread-safe in situations using `multiprocessing`, which side-steps the **GIL** by using subprocesses instead of threads?

https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ProcessPoolExecutor](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L497) uses multiprocessing.queues.Queue for the [call queue](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L555) and a mp_context.SimpleQueue (multiprocessing) for the [result queue](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py#L562) - which are used to communicate between a local thread and the processes.

[Nice graphic of ProcessPoolExecutor](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/concurrent/futures/process.py)

---

- concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor *stuff* uses multiprocessing Queues to communicate between threads and processes.
- The multiprocessing.queues.Queue docs specifically state it is thread **and** process safe
- At the bottom of the [queue documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html) there is a *note* referring to the multiprocessing.Queue object `... for use in a multi-processing (rather than multi-threading) context`

Comment: Does that mean that I can replace the combination `ThreadPoolExecutor/queue.Queue` with `ProcessPoolExecutor/multiprocessing.queues.Queue` and everything will just work? Why are you talking about call queue and result queue? I just want a queue for producer/consumer pattern.

Comment: @Shuzheng I was trying to point out, by referencing the source, that the concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor uses the multiprocessing.queues.Queue - implying there is a reason for that, I imagined you'd work your way through the sources to see how They did it..  I added a bit to my answer - let me know if you think my answer is deficient and I'll delete it.

Comment: `Does that mean that I can replace ...` in my experience yes.

Comment: Where do you see that `.. for use in a multi-processing ...` note? I can't find it here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py. Also, do you know how Python creates the subprocesses? Is the whole interpreter forked, or how is the callable executed in the new subprocess?

Comment: @Shuzheng Sorry - added a link. I was referring to the Python documentation for the `queue` module in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Queue` developed for this in the `multiprocessing` library

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue
```

This uses sockets to send byte data which is thread-safe.

Comment: So, to answer my question completely, `queue.Queue` is only thread-safe when accessed by multiple threads (respecting GIL), not by multiple processes (side-stepping GIL)? Why are sockets thread-safe?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not a matter of thread safety, but rather that `queue.Queue` won't work at all between different processes, while `multiprocessing.Queue` will.